# C# and Rx: testing a timeout

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I've implemented an observer for a FileSystemWatcher. The idea is to track copies in a folder and wait until copy is finished. Once done, let's do something with copied files.
I've tried my implementation on a small program and it works. What I wanted to do is to make it more formal using unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestIsFileWritingFinished()
    {
        try
        {
            var dirName = Path.GetTempPath()+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
            if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
            {
                Directory.Delete(dirName, true);
            }
            var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
            
            var observer = new FileSystemObserver(dirName, "*.*", true)
                        .ChangedFiles
                        .Where(x => (new FileInfo(x.FullPath)).Length > 0)
                        .Select(x => x.Name);
            var timeout = observer.Timeout(/*DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1)*/TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            var filesChanged = new List<string>();
            var terminated = false;
            timeout.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine, ()=>terminated=true);

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var origin = @"C:\Users\David\ResultA";
            CopyDirectory(origin, dirName, true);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("nap for 5s");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //Directory.Delete(dirName, true);
            Assert.IsTrue(terminated);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

So, when timeout happens, I expect the boolean to be true. But looks like it's not.
Any idea about what's wrong with my test?
Thanks in advance, your suggestions will be appreciated,

Kind regards,

Comment: `Threap.Sleep` is generally not a good idea in unit test.
With RX you can time travel with the help of a Scheduler. You can pass the scheduler to the observable. In your unit test you can use `TestScheduler` as a stub for scheduler.
Have look at http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html
Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi L01NL, thanks for your suggestion, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Even thought there is a `Timeout` operator, I find it is a bit of an anti-pattern. It's like programming with exceptions. I find the following pattern more useful:

```
IObservable<bool> query =
    Observable.Amb(
        source.LastAsync().Select(x => true),
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)).Select(x => false));
```

This is effectively running `source` to completion and then returns `true`, but if the `Timer` completes first it returns `false`.

So, in your code, I'd try something like this:

```
var dirName = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
{
    Directory.Delete(dirName, true);
}
var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);

var observer =
    new FileSystemObserver(dirName, "*.*", true)
        .ChangedFiles
        .Where(x => (new FileInfo(x.FullPath)).Length > 0)
        .Select(x => x.Name);
        
var result =
    Observable.Amb(
        observer.ToArray().Select(x => true),
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(x => false));

var query =
    result.Zip(Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        var origin = @"C:\Users\David\ResultA";
        CopyDirectory(origin, dirName, true);
    }), (r, s) => r);

var terminated = query.Wait();

Assert.IsTrue(terminated);
```

That totally avoids any pesky sleeps.